# Rotate to fire Segue in iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I have storyboard which has a tab bar controller. When the device rotates I want to move to a different screen, i.e. not show the same layout sideways but show something completely different.

In iOS 5 I achieved this with the following code in the UITabBarControllerDelegate

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:      (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {    
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"toGraph" sender: self];
    }

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

In iOS 6 this method is no longer called.  All the methods I can see deal with when the *view* is rotated, but not when the *device* is rotated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So really I shouldn't have been looking for a *view* rotation, but rather a *device* rotation. After discovering the UIDevice class I was able to use the AlternateViews sample code (just search for AlternateViews in the Documentation Organizer) to get everything I needed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.delegate = self;

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // We must add a delay here, otherwise we'll swap in the new view
    // too quickly and we'll get an animation glitch
    [self performSelector:@selector(showGraphs) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)showGraphs
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"toGraph" sender: self];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }

    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Autorotation has changed in iOS 6. Here's a thread on Apple dev forums on the issue: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/166544?tstart=30

Here are some more threads:
http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=41ED2FC151397D4AD4A5A60&currentPage=1

https://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?fid=B35F4D4F5EF6B293A717EB5&tid=B35F4D4F5EF6B293A717EB5

The most relevant post from these to your issue seems to be the following:

> Got it working...for tabbed apps, replaced this line in the appDelegate: 
>   [self.window addSubview:[self.rootApp.rootTabBarController view]];
>
> with this: 
>   [self.window.rootViewController = self.rootApp.rootTabBarController view];
>
> And to get non-tabbed apps, replaced this line: 
>   [self.window addSubview:[self.rootApp.rootNavController view]];
>
> with this: 
>   [self.window.rootViewController = self.rootApp.rootNavController view];

Comment: Hi Darth, thanks for your help, but my issue was with not being able to detect a device rotation, all of this is to do with _view_ rotation.  Essentially I was using a dirty hack before, I've now done it 'properly' and it works.